# WPF ComboBox not Firing on selection

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I have a ComboBox, shown below. Why isn't the code-behind always firing?

XAML:

```xml
<ComboBox   Height="23"
                        Name="cbAppendCreate"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Width="120"
                        Margin="{StaticResource ConsistentMargins}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CbCreateAppendItems}"
                        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CbAppendCreate,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

CodeBehind:

```cs
private string cbAppendCreate;
public string CbAppendCreate {
    get {
        //....
        return cbAppendCreate
    }
    set { //This doesn't fire when selecting the first of 2 Items, 
          //but always fires when selecting the 2nd of two items 
          //....
         cbAppendCreate = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my simple setup. Post more code, or I can post mine, if you want.

Comment: @Haspemulator I'm happy to send my project as well.  I would like to see it, if it differs from the code that I have posted above.  I am following MVVM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post my working code here, it's very simple. I've just created a default WPF app using VS2012 template. Here's MainWindow.xaml content:

```
<Window x:Class="
    WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox   Height="23"
                    Name="cbAppendCreate"
                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Width="120"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CbCreateAppendItems}"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CbAppendCreate,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CbAppendCreate}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

Here's code-behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
    {
    public class DataSource
    {
        public List<string> CbCreateAppendItems { get; set; }
        public string CbAppendCreate { get; set; }
        public DataSource()
        {
            CbCreateAppendItems = new List<string>() { "create", "append" };
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new DataSource();
        }
    }
}
```

When I select different values in combo-box, the TextBlock updates to the same value, hence the VM's property is also updated.

Comment: I'm accepting this because it works and I've created a working example that fires on every selection, but my problem persists with the original.   The setter is not firing on a ComboBox value change whatsoever. I am not sure where the bug is.